# Python Logger Invalid Argument for FileHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, rest, logging

Hi when I am writing the following code in python

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('ThingsSpeakRESTAPI.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The log file is created in the name ThingsSpeakRESTAPI.log

But If I do:

```
filename = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+"LOG.log"
print(filename)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Then I get the following error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Both are in str then why is not taking variable with a string value, but a string value in itself ??

Comment: If i copy your code and print it out it shows: `filename = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+"LOG.log"` `print(filename)` Result: `2021-11-01T14:02:31.610468LOG.log` filenames cannot contain the char `:`

Answer (score 0):

Filenames cannot contain `:` characters.

You could do:

`filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%f")+"LOG.log"`

Here you format the string yourself and in that way make sure the filename doesn't contain illegal characters.

Result:

`2021-11-01_14.10.46.091188LOG.log`